# How to build a JSON like this using js?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to build a JSON like this and send it server via form post. All these json values are from select options in the UI.

```
 {  
   "pages":[  
      {  
         "id":"messages",
         "name":"yourinbox",
         "value":"ACTIVE"
      },
      {  
         "id":"emails",
         "name":"newmail",
         "value":"INACTIVE"
      }
   ]
}
```

I've tried with below code, but i'm not able to get the correct format. 
    Any help? Thanks!

```
var self = this;
var request = new HttpRequest();
this.form$ = $(selector);
self.form$.find('.loader').hide();

this.onSubmit = function(e){
hideSubmit();
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
var parsedata = {};
var data = {};
var selectedOptions = self.form$.find('select');
for (var i = 0, ii = selectedOptions.length; i < ii; ++i) {
var input = selectedOptions[i];
data["name"] = input.id;
data["value"] = input.value;
parsedata.push(data); } };
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? `self` refers to `window` ... What are the other properties/methods supposed to be?

Comment: I'm able to get all the select items, there is no problem with self. Updated post with rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the rough approach; Feel free to improvise.

```js
let object = {"pages" : []};

let options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");

for(i=0;i<options.length; i++) {
  object["pages"][i] = {}
  object["pages"][i]["id"] = options[i].getAttribute('id');
  object["pages"][i]["value"] = options[i].getAttribute('value');
  let activeStatus = options[i].getAttribute('selected');
  if(activeStatus == "true") object["pages"][i]["activeStatus"] = activeStatus;
  else object["pages"][i]["activeStatus"] = false;
}

console.log(object)
```

```html
<select>
<option id="1" value="One" selected=true>One</option>
<option id="2" value="Two">Two</option>
<option id="3" value="Three">Three</option>
<option id="4" value="Four">Four</option>
</select>
```